# foreach - Looping through specific values of observations to get a specific output

Tags: stata

I have a list of 50 states ranging over of 5 years from 2000 to 2004

```
State        year   

Alaska       2000  
Alaska       2001  
Alaska       2002  
Alaska       2003  
Alaska       2004  
Alabama      2000      
Alabama      2001    
Alabama      2002    
Alabama      2003    
Alabama      2004     
Arizona      2000      
Arizona      2001    
Arizona      2002    
Arizona      2003    
Arizona      2004  
Arkansas     2000      
Arkansas     2001    
Arkansas     2002    
Arkansas     2003    
Arkansas     2004  
Colorado     2000      
Colorado     2001    
Colorado     2002    
Colorado     2003    
Colorado     2004
```

I want to create a `foreach` loop using `local`, containing only Alabama and Colorado. 
The end goal is to have a dummy variable called `dummy`, which will be `0` for all States, and `1` for Alabama and Colorado for the years spanning 2002-2004.

This will be the final dataset:

```
State        year       dummy

Alaska       2000         0
Alaska       2001         0  
Alaska       2002         0  
Alaska       2003         0  
Alaska       2004         0  
Alabama      2000         0     
Alabama      2001         0    
Alabama      2002         1    
Alabama      2003         1    
Alabama      2004         1     
Arizona      2000         0      
Arizona      2001         0    
Arizona      2002         0    
Arizona      2003         0    
Arizona      2004         0  
Arkansas     2000         0      
Arkansas     2001         0    
Arkansas     2002         0    
Arkansas     2003         0    
Arkansas     2004         0  
Colorado     2000         0      
Colorado     2001         0    
Colorado     2002         1    
Colorado     2003         1    
Colorado     2004         1
```

This is what I have attempted so far.

```
use "States.dta", replace
gen dummy = 0
local States "Alabama Colorado"
local i=1
foreach ii of local States {
replace dummy_treated = 1 if States == `ii' & year >=2002
local i=`i' + 1
}
```

When I run this, it produces the output only for Alabama, not including Colorado.
When I closed the file and re-ran the program, the error message says

```
Alabama not found
r(111);
```

What could I do to resolve this?

Comment: I have not tried to correct inconsistencies in what you show us. You first list values of `State` but your variable in code is called `States`. The listing leaves ambiguous whether you have a string variable or are showing a numeric variable with value labels.  You `generate` a variable called `dummy` but `replace` a variable called `dummy_treated`. Further, initialising `local i` and then incrementing it in the loop is harmless but pointless.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info for detailed suggestions on asking better Stata questions. The highlights are showing Stata data as code that will reproduce the data accurately and unambiguously and showing us code that will faithfully reproduce the problem reported.

Comment: I realize the confusion with the inconsistencies. Should I edit it now and make the changes?

Comment: Up to you, but the real puzzle is why you claim that this code ever worked, even with small variations corrected and partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer comes in two parts.

First: Your approach can be avoided by one command line

```
gen wanted = inlist(States, "Alabama", "Colorado")  ///
& inrange(year, 2002, 2004)
```

No loop is needed. The right-hand side here evaluates as 1 when the joint condition is true and 0 when it is false, precisely what an indicator variable (you say "dummy", a term better avoided, but there you go) is required to be.

Second: What is wrong with your code? Your report is contradictory because you state that the code worked once but not on repetition. I can only believe that if you were working with different versions of the data. The error message you got is easy to explain. You were testing whether

```
States == Alabama
```

which to Stata makes sense if and only if you have a variable with the name `Alabama` or exceptionally a string scalar with the same name. You have no such variable or scalar, and Stata throws out the command because it can't find what it thinks you are asking it to use. The error arises because `States` is evidently a string variable and you need to test whether

```
States == "Alabama"
```

the double quotes being essential to specify a literal string value rather than the name of a string variable or scalar.

Although it is quite unnecessary, this would be a legal loop given a string variable `States` with values like `Alabama`:

```
gen dummy = 0 

foreach s in Alabama Colorado { 
    replace dummy = 1 if inlist(States, "`s'") & inrange(year, 2002, 2004) 
}
```

`year >= 2002` is fine for your example, but I mention `inrange()` as a useful function in this context.

Comment: the only reason I wanted to use a loop: the next thing I want to do is set dummy =1 for New York and Ohio for years {2003, 2004}.

Comment: First, as a generality, we can address only what you tell us and can't know what else you have in mind. Second, on that information there is still no need for a loop. You can build that into the same command or issue another one. Even if there are yet more conditions to come, your code will be then clearer to read and much easier to write and debug.  Loops are wonderful  when they are the right tool, but not when you are struggling to fit a series of idiosyncratic conditions into an all-embracing loop.  By all means ask a more general or different question if you have one.

Comment: `inlist` has a limit of 10 strings. What would I have to do to run the same command for more than 10 States? Or is this something that should be a different question?

Comment: I realized I can overcome this by using the or condition. `gen wanted = inlist(States, "Alabama", "Colorado"......"9th_state") |  inlist(States, "10th_State", "12th"......"15th_state") `

Comment: That's not literal syntax, but otherwise indeed; that's one solution.